# Rails 3.2 ApplicationController how to inherit modules ApplicationController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my rails 3.2 project, I have some controllers like this:

```
/app/controllers/application_controller.rb
/app/controllers/college/application_controller.rb
/app/controllers/college/actors_controller.rb
```

The content of /app/controllers/college/actors_controller.rb like:

```
class College::ActorsController < College::ApplicationController
end
```

The content of /app/controllers/college/application_controller.rb like:

```
class College::ApplicationController < ApplicationController
  before_filter do
    puts "welcome"
  end
end
```

If I modify the controller, reload the web browser.
The console can be output string "welcome".
But when I shutdown the webrick, and restart webrick, then reload the web browser, the console doesn't output "welcome"

It looks like College::ApplicationController not be loaded ?

And how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We ran into something similar and fully defined class definitions solved our problem.

It's worth trying to change

```
class College::ActorsController < College::ApplicationController
```

to

```
class College::ActorsController < ::College::ApplicationController
```

and

```
class College::ApplicationController < ApplicationController
```

to

```
class College::ApplicationController < ::ApplicationController
```